# Custom "New Quote" Button - Empty Fields

Tags: custom-button, quote

I'm new to learning SFDC customisation, and have been tasked with improving it on request of our sales team. All we need is to pre-fill the "Opportunity Name" and "Expiry Date" fields, but I have hit a wall after nearly a whole day...

I can't seem to create an Action for record type Quote, so instead I am trying a custom button using URL hacking as follows:

```
/lightning/o/Quote/new?defaultFieldValues=
Name={!Opportunity.Name},
OpportunityId={!Opportunity.Id},
AccountId={!Account.Id},
ExpirationDate={!Text(Opportunity.CloseDate)}&
backgroundContext=/lightning/r/Opportunity/{!Opportunity.Id}/view
```

This works nicely - but it leaves all other fields such as "Prepared For" and addresses (usually pre-filled on the vanilla "New Quote" button) blank. I am having trouble allocating either of these fields.

Is there a way to only change fields we specify, or instead how to allocate the Opp's Primary Contact Role (name, email and phone) and Account's addresses?

Any help gratefully received - apologies if I have omitted any important details, just ask.